# Contacts recognized in one app, but not the other?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, contacts

Since the update from yesterday, it seems that the contacts from my Sim card aren't recognized any more in the Phone and SMS app. I double checked the sim card's content with the [SIM Card Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rachunek.android.simcard) app and they are all there.

So why doesn't the SMS and Phone app recognize them? When I choose 'Show contacts > Sim Card' it shows *0 contacts*, which should be more, because as mentioned earlier they are still on the sim card.

I'm using a Medion P4013, which is using Android 4.0.4

Answer (score 0):

Import the contacts from SIM card to the phone memory. My phone also does not support viewing SIM contacts directly. Importing is a simple process. Just tap `Contacts>Menu>Import contacts>SIM card>Select all>Import`.That's it.

Comment: I tried, but when I import from card it only shows 2 named and 5 unnamed contact cards. The app just doesn't seem to find the rest.

Comment: Use phone's inbuilt Contacts app instead of third-party apps.

Comment: I am... I'm using the contacts app MEDION shipped with it. Maybe using a third party app might work though. I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmm... I'm just going for the easier problem/solution: have you imported your contacts?! 
 - Go to your contacts 
 - Tap the menu button 
 - Select the import option 
 - Select import contacts from sim card

Comment: I tried, but when I import from card it only shows 2 named and 5 unnamed contact cards. The app just doesn't seem to find the rest.